# Can I change the input (GetKeyState) and output (Send,) keys based on user input (preferably InputBox)?

Tags: autohotkey, inputbox

I want to make a script that will temporarily create a Turbo button, with the input/output customizable per run. Ideally, something like

```
InputBox, TriggerKey, Input Trigger Here    ; Custom turbo trigger
InputBox, TurboKey, Input Turbo Button Here ; and custom turbo key
while NOT GetKeyState("F12", "P") { ; Just so the loop would close if you ran this
  while GetKeyState(%TriggerKey%, "P") { ; when the inputted trigger is held...
    Send, %TurboKey%                     ; rapid-fire the inputted turbo
    Sleep 50
  }
}
```

The above code hasn't worked, and I'm not sure if it's a GetKeyState/InputBox formatting issue, a user input issue (I haven't been putting in the right strings), or I just can't make a customized turbo like this.

The most recent idea I've had for this was just to write and run another .ahk file with the inputted keys, but if this is possible without having to manage multiple files, that would be great.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you ar trying to accomplish.  Could you please explain what you want to do?  What is "trigger"?  So you want something to constantly happen as long as the `F12` and `P` keys are not held?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be better accomplished with the `Hotkey` command.  This way whatever is entered in your input box as the `TriggerKey` will fire whatever code is under the label.

```
InputBox, TriggerKey, Input Trigger Here    ; Custom turbo trigger
InputBox, TurboKey, Input Turbo Button Here ; and custom turbo key

Hotkey, % TriggerKey, TriggerKey
Return

TriggerKey:
    While ! GetKeyState("F12", "P") 
    {
        Send, %TurboKey%
        Sleep 50
    }
Return
```